# Equal sign in javascript mailto url getting parsed on Android

Tags: javascript, php, android

I have a web app that sends a URL link in the body of the email from a button `onclick="email();"`.  The url is a php page with `.php?id=` and everything after equal sign is getting truncated when sent from an Android device.
I have tried encoding the URL but nothing is working...
I know the `mailto` tag uses the `=` sign as a parsing character...but still cannot figure this out.

Here is code.

```
  function email() {
  window.location.href = "mailto:?subject=LIVE link!&body=Here is a link for a LIVE demo!%0D%0Awww.domain.ca/scores/" + sport + "php%3Fid%3d" + id   +"%0D%0A%0D%0AThanks";
  }
```

Any suggestions or experience in this?
Works fine on all other platforms (iOS, Windows etc)

Comment: You should use `encodeURIComponent` instead of trying to do the encoding yourself.

Comment: I corrected the code to use the `encodeURIComponent` and it still does not work

Comment: Probably unrelated, but aren't you missing `.` before `php%3F`?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this, but I don't have an android phone, and it seems like the android emulators at BrowserStack don't have mail clients configured, so mailto: links don't work.

Comment: I have the "." in my real code...I must edited it out accidentally when I was formatting my code for stackoverflow

Comment: Well, got it resolved,.. Turns out it is specific to Outlook app on Android.  The tester removed Outlook from their device and it worked properly.  Not going to worry about uses that run Outlook on an Android device...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out is was specific to Outlook app on Android device.

Answer (score 0):

This is from one of my sites..

```
     <?php
    if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
 }
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['mail'];
$message = $_POST['appointment'];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
echo "Bad email value!";
exit;
}

$email_from = 'Client';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Booking an appointment";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n"."Here 
is the message:\n $message";
$to = "somebody@hotmail.com ";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: aboutUs.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
          '(\r+)',
          '(\t+)',
          '(%0A+)',
          '(%0D+)',
          '(%08+)',
          '(%09+)'
          );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
  {
  return true;
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the code, but how does this code answer the question?